# repopulate of text item value gives error

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I want to repopulate of text items,it shows null value after insert

```
<input type="number" id="primaryincome1"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
value="<?php echo (!isset($student1['noc'])) ? 0 : $student1['noc'] ?>" >

<input type="number" id="primaryincome2"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
value="<?php echo (!isset($student2['noc'])) ? 0 : $student2['noc'] ?>">

<input type="number" id="primaryincome3"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
value="<?php echo (!isset($student3['noc'])) ? 0 : $student2['noc'] ?>" >

<input type="number" id="primaryincom4"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
value="<?php echo (!isset($student4['noc'])) ? 0 : $student2['noc'] ?>" >

<input type="number" id="primaryincome5"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
value="<?php echo (!isset($student5['noc'])) ? 0 : $student2['noc'] ?>" >

<input type="number" id="primaryincome6"  min="1"  max="999" name="noc[]" 
value="<?php echo (!isset($student6['noc'])) ? 0 : $student2['noc'] ?>"
```

Controller:

```
$certids = $this->input->post('certid');  
$nocs = $this->input- >post('noc'); 
$result = array();
foreach ($certids as $index=>$certid) 
{
    $result[] = $certid . '_' . $nocs[$index];
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($result);echo '</pre>';
```

after I made changes in the input item, it gives an output:

```
Array
  (
[0] => 1_2
[1] => 2_2
[2] => 3_2
[3] => 4_2
[4] => 5_2
[5] => 6_2
[6] => 7_
  )
```

First value only be inserting. remaining values are inserted as '0';
How do I solve this error? I need help.

Comment: Where are you attempting to define `$student2`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. what you are trying to achieve? What problem you are facing? Explain properly.